# Khutba (Friday Sermons) - Where exactly is text?

Tags: jumuah, khutbah

I need to know about the Khutba (Friday sermon) recited by Imam on Friday, Are those a verses' of Quran? Are those quoted from some Hadith? I find it partly different for some Fridays.

Can some explain this? Where exactly can we look for it and the meaning/translation of each sermon?

I heard the last sermon is the biggest one covering many aspects of socio-economin-spiritual life of man.

Comment: Do you mean the last seron of Prophet (PBUH+SAWS) ? Or do you mean any Khutba ?

Comment: I am referring both. Where can see the exact translations for them? And where is the arabic source for them?

Comment: The one held by Imam on friday is individual - i.e. the Imam chooses which topics to speak about and refers to Quran and Sunna regarding those topics. IF you want that in english you will need to ask the mosque whether they have such a translation available (some do, some don't).

Comment: As for the last sermon of Prophet (PBUH+SAWS) you can find it in Bukhari for example... some links: http://www.iqrasense.com/about-islam/the-last-sermon-khutbah-of-prophet-muhammad-farewell-sermon.html , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Farewell_Sermon , http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/523/ , http://www.islamhelpline.com/node/2617

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comments above:

The sermon held by Imam on friday is individual - i.e. the Imam chooses which topics to speak about and refers to Quran and Sunna regarding those topics. IF you want that in english you will need to ask the mosque whether they have such a translation available (some do, some don't).

As for the last sermon of Prophet (PBUH+SAWS) you can find it in Bukhari for example... some links:

- http://www.iqrasense.com/about-islam/the-last-sermon-khutbah-of-prophet-muhammad-farewell-sermon.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Farewell_Sermon
- http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/523/
- http://www.islamhelpline.com/node/2617